# Seleção top 3 where distinct

Tags: sql, sql-select, distinct

Boa tarde galera.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925176/sql-server-2008-top-10-and-distinct-together

Preciso de uma ajuda, tentei ver na sessão acima porem não consegui resolver meu problema.

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu preciso fazer um seleção de produtos e todos separados unicamente por fornecedor, exemplo.

Imagina que no meu banco tem um cadastro de produto e fornecedor, exemplo, bolas de futebol, e eu tenho cadastrado 5 bolas da Penalty, 19 da Adidas e 3 da Umbro, eu queria trazer uma bola de cada fornecedor. 
1 Penalty, 1 Adidas, 1 Umbro.

```
SELECT 
    distinct top 3 sup.Name as Supplier, pr.CommercialName
FROM Product pr
    FULL OUTER JOIN ProductSupplier AS ps ON (pr.IdProduct = ps.IdProduct)
    FULL OUTER JOIN Supplier AS sup ON (ps.IdSupplier = sup.IdSupplier)
WHERE 
pr.CASNo in ('516849','99879846','68487498','984987','6510016847') or 
pr.IdProduct in ('2270')
```

Porém ao invés de ele trazer apenas um produto de cada fornecedor ele trás uns itens aleatórios que estão no meio do banco.

Alteração --

```
CREATE TABLE Produto (
   id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
   nome varchar(100),
);

CREATE TABLE Fornecedor (
   id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
   nome varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE produtoFornecedor(
   id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
   idProduto int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES produto(id),
   idFornecedor int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES fornecedor(id));
```

Esse é o banco basicamente meu select que eu tentei foi esse:

```
SELECT 
    distinct sup1.nome as Fornecedor,
    (
        select 
            top 1 (pr2.nome)
        from Produto pr2
            inner JOIN Fornecedor AS sup2 ON (ps.idFornecedor = sup2.idFornecedor)
        WHERE sup2.nome = sup1.nome
    ) as produto
FROM Produto pr
    FULL OUTER JOIN Produto AS ps ON (pr.idProduto = ps.idProduto)
    FULL OUTER JOIN Fornecedor AS sup1 ON (ps.idFornecedor = sup1.idFornecedor)
```

[image: Resultado]

Essa é a massa de dados que retornou, porém pegou um null e repetiu os produtos por algum motivo que não estou conseguindo ver

Comment: Para a gente te ajudar melhor, poste a estrutura das tabelas e registros no http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a81ee/8 eu não sabia como que vocês iam precisar que eu colocasse nas tabelas, mas basicamente duas tabelas normais e uma tabela que recebe os ids, não conseguir inserir os ids na tabela produtoFornecedor por que eles ficam mudando sempre que eu executo um script

Comment: Ajustei o teu código no sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8f92/3. Poderia me passar o resultado experado com os dados que tem lá:?

Comment: Então dai a ideia seria pegar um produto por vez, tendo base de um fornecedor, pois não pode repetir o fornecedor. No link que você me mandou seria trazer da tabela produtoFornecedor, trazer o id 1 e id 3 que vai diferenciar os fornecedores, não sei se consegui te explicar melhor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite,

Bom, agora com as novas informações , segue adaptação que fiz da minha primeira sugestão com o novo cenário que você passou (OBS: Não pude testar os comandos, mas explicarei a ideia e você corrige qualquer problema nomenclatura e/ou sintaxe).

1- Nesta parte é listado o nome do fornecedor.

```
  SELECT 
    distinct forn.nome as Fornecedor,
```

2- Este subselect segue a mesma lógica que citei antes.. para cada fornecedor distinto ele vai selecionar um produto desse fornecedor e listar.

```
    (select ps.nome
  from produto ps
 where ps.idProduto = pf.idProduto 
  limit 1) as produto
```

3- A tabela produtoFornecedor é a tabela onde tem as informações que você precisa, pois nela você tem o cruzamento de Produto X Fornecedor.

```
from produtoFornecedor pf
```

4- Realizei o join com a tabela de Fornecedor para que no passo 1 possa ser listado o respectivo nome do fornecedor, em vez do código.

```
INNER JOIN Fornecedor AS forn ON pf.idFornecedor = forn.idFornecedor
```

5- Segue a query final:

```
 SELECT 
    distinct forn.nome as Fornecedor,
    (select ps.nome
  from produto ps
 where ps.idProduto = pf.idProduto 
  limit 1) as produto
FROM produtoFornecedor pf
  INNER JOIN Fornecedor AS forn ON pf.idFornecedor = forn.idFornecedor
```

Essa sua query estava um tanto confusa. A tabela no FROM estava a de produtos e fizesse vários outer joins. Sugiro que você dê uma olhada na diferença de INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN (right, left, etc) para sanar eventuais dúvidas.

Boa sorte e bom estudo!

---

Bom dia,

Baseado na sua descrição de pegar um de cada modelo, criei um exemplo similar em MySQL para você se basear.

```
+-----------+---------+
| nm_cidade | sg_pais |
+-----------+---------+
| Brasil1   | BR      |
| Brasil2   | BR      |
| Londres   | EN      |
| Londres1  | EN      |
| Paris     | FR      |
| Paris1    | FR      |
| Paris2    | FR      |
+-----------+---------+
```

Você precisa retornar uma cidade de cada país, certo? Uma forma simples de fazer é primeiramente selecionar os países existentes distintos:

```
 select distinct sg_pais
 from cidade c1;

 Retorno:
+---------+
| sg_pais |
+---------+
| BR      |
| EN      |
| FR      |
+---------+
```

Em seguida você faz um subselect, iguala os países e usa o limit 1 pra retornar apenas um.

```
select distinct sg_pais,
  (select nm_cidade
   from cidade c2
 where c1.sg_pais = c2.sg_pais
  limit 1)
 from cidade c1; 

 Retorno:
+--------------+
| sg_pais      |
+--------------+
| BR   Brasil1 |
| EN   Londres |
| FR   Paris   |
+--------------+
```

Neste exemplo os nomes das cidades (Brasil1, Londres e Paris) virão aleatoriamente porque não passei nenhum filtro no subselect, apenas solicitei um registro através do limit 1. Caso você tenha que filtrar, inclua as condições dentro do subselect.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui, porem ele me retornou apenas um produto da forma que eu fiz, pois adaptei para minha necessidade, não sei por onde passar minha consulta, mas vou publicar aqui pelo document do Google Drive : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Bh2WeKWYLqjhiBBjKfkyHl9qEuVFFdjNQy-HdU7J7aw

Comment: Quero dizer, ele fez a ideia de retornar itens com apenas um fornecedor, porem na hora de ele colocar o produto ele apenas pegou um produto apenas exemplo: produto 1; fornecedor 1; produto 1; fornecedor 2 ...

Comment: Esse exemplo que passei resolve a questão do "eu queria trazer uma bola de cada fornecedor. 1 Penalty, 1 Adidas, 1 Umbro.". Se não é isso que você precisa, realmente não entendi o resultado esperado por você..  Edita a pergunta e põe as tabelas, campos e o que você quer de retorno para entendermos sua dúvida.

Comment: Eu tenho certeza que se eu conseguisse adaptar o script que você fez para o meu caso, com certeza que funcionaria, porém eu devo estar fazendo algo de errado, mas beleza vou passar o que eu tenho aqui, achei que pegando a ideia conseguiria reproduzir aqui

Comment: Sim, se sua dúvida é realmente essa, basta uma adaptação no seu script para funcionar. Sugiro você realizar uma nova tentativa e, caso não consiga, poste na pergunta as tabelas/colunas , alguns dados de exemplo e o resultado esperado. Assim poderemos ajudá-lo certeiramente.

Answer (score 0):

Opa consegui valeu pela dica, Marcelo.

O que eu estava fazendo, antes eu estava fazendo a comparação pelo nome, porem deu certo quando eu igualei os IDs da tabela dos fornecedores e na tabela associativa ProdutoFornecedor. Ficou assim o código

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT sup.Name,
    (
        SELECT top 1 prd.CommercialName FROM Product AS prd

            FULL OUTER JOIN ProductSupplier AS pSu ON ( prd.IdProduct = pSu.IdProduct)

            FULL OUTER JOIN Supplier AS supJoin ON ( pSu.IdSupplier = supJoin.IdSupplier)

        WHERE pSu.IdSupplier = sup.IdSupplier
    ) AS fornecedor
FROM Supplier AS sup
```

Alguém sabe um nome melhor para o tópico caso alguém queria chegar nesse resultado também?